# How come we are running redis and redisearch on same port 6379, What I understand is redisearch need to be install and run with redis

Tags: redis, redisearch

How come we are running Redis and redisearch on the same port 6379, What I understand is redisearch need to be installed and run with Redis, it will work on data stored in Redis, or do we need to move data to redisearch and then create index?

Answer (score 2):

RediSearch is a Redis module which runs, as all modules, within Redis itself: it doesn't open any additional port on its own, as all the requests are handled by the hosting Redis server itself.

With that being said, I would suggest to read the [quick start for RediSearch](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/quick_start/).